# Is the amount of data sent from firebase limited only to the branch asked for?

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

There is a very large number of numerical leaves (say 1,000,000) under a branch looking like this:

- car

  - 1
  - 2

There is no index on any part of this branch.  If we ask for car/2 in this way:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()
ref.child("car").child("2").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { 
    (snapshot) in
})
```

will this cause any other part of the car branch to be read other than the child 2 we asked for?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. When you load `car/2` it only looks at and returns that specific branch. Other children of `car` are not touched in any way.

Accessing by a direct path like this does not require an index. Only if you query on `car`, will you need an index on that level for the values of child nodes that you query on.